# Kafka Consumer - How can I do Replay/Get the same message from kafka broker in case my service is down/some exception occurred

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

what's my understanding is as of now when I set `auto commit to false` and `ack mode to manual immediate` then any exception occurs. I'm not going to ack to broker. So when I restart my consumer process with same `consumergroupid` I need to read the message again since I didn't ack.

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "testtopic", groupId = "testgroupID")
    public void listenGroupFoo(String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offsets,
                               @Header(value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required =false) Integer key,
                               @Payload String payload,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts
                               ) {
                    
                     //performing some process like insert to DB or 
                     calling some downstream process, once this processes is done 
                     I would like to inform kafka broker that I'm done with processing 
                     by implementing  acknowledgment.acknowledge(); for each individual message
                     one by one
    }
```

and  **ConsumerFactory** config is

```
enable.auto.commit = false
auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

and **ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory** config is

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what will happen, unless you ack the next record in the partition; in that case the failed record will be skipped; Kafka only keeps a "last" committed offset.

If you throw an exception for the failed record, by default, the framework will rewind the partition and redeliver the failed record up to 9 times; see [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling).

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated you're help. I have retested now it worked.
so the part I missed is -> Kafka only keeps a "last" committed offset.